# Error al refrescar aplicacion Angular 10 en Azure

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core

He creado un proyecto WebApi en NetCore 2.1 y un proyecto web con Angular 10. He cambiado la ruta de compilación de Angular (dist) para que el build lo haga en la carpeta wwwroot del WebApi.

Aparte he creado en Azure un App Service donde publico el conjunto final (el WebApi con la web dentro de wwwroot). Una vez publicado, el WebApi funciona correctamente y si accedo al [dominio]/index.html, se enruta la aplicación Angular a [dominio]/login y hasta ahí todo bien; la aplicación funciona y se comunica con el WebApi.

El problema lo tengo cuando pulso F5 para que se refresque; me aparece un error 404 ya que [dominio]/login no es una ruta física. Llevo ya 3 días dándole vueltas, buscando por todos lados y probando soluciones que no me funcionan (incluso falla la de añadir el # en la ruta).

¿Alguno ha tenido este problema? Espero alguien me pueda ayudar pues ya necesito solucionar esto y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que me podáis proporcionar.

**Actualización 1**

En Azure, dentro del app service donde tengo todo desplegado, he visto que aparecen subidas todas las dlls y un archivo web.config que se ha creado automaticamente. Ademas, esta subida la carpeta wwwroot del api donde coloqué mi aplicación angular.

He metido en el config lo siguiente:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!api).*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

pongo la cadena "api" excluida en la condición porque cuando probé con .* el api también me lo redireccionaba al index.

Antes funcionaba bien tanto el api como la web, pero al refrescar la web daba un error. Ahora con esto, el api sigue funcionando pero al acceder a /index.html ni si quiera enruta.

Al ver el codigo en el depurador, veo que el código de la pagina index.html de angular se carga, pero no se ejecuta, ya que me aparecen un error en la consola.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (aparece una linea por cada archivo js y si pincho en el enlace al archivo se va al inicio del codigo del index.html)

¿Alguien sabe que está pasando?

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes ahora definido, se carga la página index.html pero, cuando se hacen las peticiones de los ficheros JS y CSS, también estás entregando el fichero index.html... y la etiqueta `<html>` provoca el fallo que estás viendo: no es javascript válido y da error de sintaxis en el compilador

Comment: No conozco la sintaxis de IIS(uso nginx), pero una solución sería poner index.html como resultado de toda petición que vaya a dar un error 404 y NO tenga /api/ en su URL. Por otro lado, ¿Es posible que te falte cambiar el valor de `<base href>`?

Comment: @PabloLozano depurando he visto que es cierto lo que estas comentando pero entonces hay algo que no entiendo... el bloque de condiciones no deberia hacer que eso no pasase ? entiendo que al poner esas condiciones le estoy diciendo que devuelva el html siempre que no sea ni archivo ni directorio... porque pasa entonces eso con los js ?

Comment: Mira la URL que se está pididendo, si tienes el tag base mal configurado te van a fallar

Answer (score 0):

En tu app.module.ts  en la sección de providers agrega esta esta estrategia: `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},`

e importas esto: `import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';`